# error 'filenames' is not defined when consolidating multiple excel files

Tags: python, excel, pandas

my Python code is used to consolidate multiple excel files from folder "excel_Report"
into 1 master excel file.
i have installed all libraries: pyodbc, pandas , plyer ,glob2.
But when i execute python. there is an Error:

**"NameError: name 'filenames' is not defined"**

i don't know what is wrong with my code. Can you please help?
Thank you

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime
from plyer import notification
import glob



# getting excel files to be merged from the Desktop 
path = "T:\excel_Report"

# read all the files with extension .xlsx i.e. excel 
excel_files = glob.glob(path + "\*.xlsx")
print('File names:', filenames)

# empty data frame for the new output excel file with the merged excel files
outputxlsx = pd.DataFrame()


with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    combined_wb = app.books.add()
    for excel_file in excel_files:
        wb = app.books.open(excel_file)
        for sheet in wb.sheets:
            sheet.copy(after=combined_wb.sheets[0])
        wb.close()
    #combined_wb.sheets[0].delete()
    combined_wb.save("T:/excel_Report/test.xlsx")
    combined_wb.close()
```

Comment: You should look at the line that raises the error. You are trying to `print('File names:', filenames)`, but `filenames` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

you search for all files in the path that end with `.xlsx` and name that variable `excel_files`

```py
# read all the files with extension .xlsx i.e. excel 
excel_files = glob.glob(path + "\*.xlsx")
```

yet you try to access a variable called `filenames`

```py
print('File names:', filenames)
```

You need to fix it to

```py
print('File names:', excel_files)
```

Comment: Hi Samathingamajig, i modified as you suggested but now there is another error :   "NameError: name 'xw' is not defined"

Comment: @Phh that's because you don't have a variable called `xw` anywhere in your code, and I can't determine what it should be. Did you copy this code from somewhere else? If you did, go back there and see how `xw` is initialized.

Comment: Thank you i have add 'import xlwings as xw  # pip install xlwings
' in the code but now there is another Error : " com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)"